# Shell scripting, replace the characters using sed

Tags: shell, sed

In shell scripting, i want to replace `1bc1034gf45dna22` (16 characters total) with `1b:c1:03:4g:f4:5d:na:22` (seperated by colon) using sed.

**Edit**

I have tried

```
sed 's/\w{2}/\w{2}:/g' a.txt > b.txt
```

where `a.txt` has

```
1bc1034gf45dna22
```

Comment: I have tried sed 's/\w{2}/\w{2}:/g' a.txt > b.txt , where a.txt has 1bc1034gf45dna22

Comment: Please note that, i m trying this on AIX

Comment: You have a number of answers that demonstrably work. If they aren't working *for you* then you need to improve your question with the version numbers of your tools and some verbatim error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does

```
sed -e 's/../&:/g' -e 's/:$//' a.txt > b.txt
```

or

```
sed -e 's/\(..\)/\1:/g' -e 's/:$//' a.txt > b.txt
```

work for you?

Answer (score 2):

### Too Many Edge Cases

Sed is not an ideal tool for this job, because there are just too many edge cases. If you have very regular data and a known corpus then that's fine, but in some cases you need something more powerful that can act on *pieces* of a line independently after matching/capturing the text of interest. For example, given an input file containing:

```
foo 1bc1034gf45dna22 bar
```

you might need to extract the second column, transform it, and then substitute it in place. You might do this with Ruby as follows:

```
$ echo 'foo 1bc1034gf45dna22 bar' |
ruby -pe '
  if /(?<str>\p{Alnum}{16})/ =~ $_
    $_.sub!(str, str.scan(/../).join(?:))
  end'
```

This correctly yields:

```
foo 1b:c1:03:4g:f4:5d:na:22 bar
```

Comment: Hi, I am running this on AIX & i m not sure how does ruby works. Its giving some ruby error. Is there any alternative way to do it in shell scripting?

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\w\w\B/&:/g' file
```

Comment: @user2753366 What error do you get? This even works under the busybox Version of `sed`.

Comment: Its giving the output same it is.

Answer (score 0):

why not  `sed 's/1bc1034gf45dna22/1b:c1:03:4g:f4:5d:na:2/g' file` ?

Comment: String will change always, thats just an example string.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU/sed on any GNU/Linux distro you can use extentded regular expressions. This will convert a string of any length to a string where each two letters are separated by a colon:

```
echo 1bc1034gf45dna22 | sed -re 's/(\w{2})/\1:/g' -e 's/:$//'
```

On your AIX platform, you can leverage awk:

```
echo 1bc1034gf45dna22 | awk '
  BEGIN { FS=""; ORS=""; } 
  {
    for (i=1; i <=NF; i++) {
      if (i > 1 && (i + 1) % 2 == 0) { 
        print(":"); 
      }  

      print($i);
    }
  }'
```

Comment: I am running it on AIX & its giving:-

sed: illegal option -- r
Usage:  sed [-n] [-u] Script [File ...]
        sed [-n] [-u] [-e Script] ... [-f Script_file] ... [File ...]

Answer (score 0):

You could:

```
sed -i 's/\(\w\{2\}\)/\1:/g' file
```

This would also append a : to the end of the string. Since we cannot use positive lookahead in our sed regex syntax, we would then need to:

```
sed -i 's/:$//g' file
```

Notice that we used inplace editing for sed therefore the file will in this way altered.

Alternatively, you could use perl to use a regex that would have been /(\w{2})(?=\w{2})/$1:/g

Comment: I am running it on AIX & its giving:-

sed: illegal option -- i
Usage:  sed [-n] [-u] Script [File ...]
        sed [-n] [-u] [-e Script] ... [-f Script_file] ... [File ...]

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's always the brute-force method:

```
sed 's/\<'\
'\([0-9a-z][0-9a-z]\)'\
'\([0-9a-z][0-9a-z]\)'\
'\([0-9a-z][0-9a-z]\)'\
'\([0-9a-z][0-9a-z]\)'\
'\([0-9a-z][0-9a-z]\)'\
'\([0-9a-z][0-9a-z]\)'\
'\([0-9a-z][0-9a-z]\)'\
'\([0-9a-z][0-9a-z]\)'\
'\>/\1:\2:\3:\4:\5:\6:\7:\8/g'
```

With no leading spaces on the continuation lines the shell pastes the strings together properly.